# Multiple Redis For Spring Cache And JWT

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have actually an application that is using Redis for Cache and keeping the JWT token into redis.

My goal is to have one redis for cache, and another one for jwt token.

I dont understand how i can achieve this.
How can i say to spring to use a specific redis (here "redis-cache") for caching ?
Actually i only put @EnableCaching and it is working properly

Thanks for any help

```
spring:
  redis:
    port: 7000
    password: password123
    host: 127.0.0.1
  redis-cache: # New One
    port: 7001
    password: password123
    host: 127.0.0.1
```

I'm using redisTemplate to keep jwt token into redis

```
@Configuration
public class GenericBeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<String> jrs = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<String>(String.class);

        template.setKeySerializer(jrs);
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return template;
    }
    
}
```

```
...
@EnableCaching
public class ProjectsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectsApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```

Caching some endpoint

```
    @Cacheable(value = "users-rbac")
    public UserResponseDTO search(@PathVariable String email) {
        return userService.search(email);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom CacheManager as well, you define your cache manager as follows. Customize this as you see, for now host, port and password are fixed but you can read them from application config file using `@Value` .

```
  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    // create redis configuration
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration =
        new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("127.0.0.1", 7001);
    configuration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of("password"));
    // create a connection factory, use other connection factory if you want
    LettuceConnectionFactory factory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(configuration);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    RedisCacheWriter writer = RedisCacheWriter.nonLockingRedisCacheWriter(factory);
    // define cache cnfiguration
    RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig();
     // use Jackson serdes do not use JDK one
    cacheConfiguration.serializeValuesWith(
        SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
    // create cache manager
    return new RedisCacheManager(writer, cacheConfiguration);
  }
```